# How do I download a tarball with python?

Tags: python, file-io, tar, urllib, download

I'm trying to download a tarball by downloading the contents and then writing them to a file. This is basically how my code works:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve

contents = urlretrieve('http://example.com/file.tgz')
open('/tmp/my-tar.tgz', 'w').write(contents)
```

However, when I do that, I get an error (a `TypeError`) that says 'expected a character buffer object' in the call to `write`.

How would I write the contents of a tarball to a file?

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: What happens if you open `/tmp/my-tar.tgz` in mode `wb` instead of `w`?

Comment: Doesn't [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) return a tuple `(filename, headers)`?...

Comment: Actually, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

> urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])
>
> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary.
>   If the URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy of the
>   object exists, the object is not copied. Return a tuple (filename,
>   headers) where filename is the local file name under which the object
>   can be found, and headers is whatever the info() method of the object
>   returned by urlopen() returned (for a remote object, possibly cached).
>   Exceptions are the same as for urlopen().

`write` is complaining because it expects to get the contents of what you're trying to write, but it's actually getting a (filename, headers) tuple.

Fixed version:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve

filename, headers = urlretrieve('http://example.com/file.tgz', '/tmp/my-tar.tgz')
```

Comment: `contents` is the name of a `(filename, headers)` tuple? Isn't that misleading?

Comment: @cubuspl42 Yes, it is. Fixed.